# What are some good methods to find the "relatedness" of two bodies of text?

Tags: comparison, full-text-search, information-retrieval, string-comparison

Here's the problem -- I have a few thousand small text snippets, anywhere from a few words to a few sentences - the largest snippet is about 2k on disk.  I want to be able to compare each to each, and calculate a relatedness factor so that I can show users related information.

What are some good ways to do this?  Are there known algorithms for doing this that are any good, are there any GPL'd solutions, etc?

I don't need this to run in realtime, as I can precalculate everything.  I'm more concerned with getting good results than runtime.

I just thought I would ask the Stack Overflow community before going and writing my own thing.  There HAVE to be people out there who have found good solutions to this before.

Comment: Very underdefined question.  Upon what basis do you consider two texts to be related to each other?  Common topics?  Repeated phrases?  Length?  Complexity?  Letter frequency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These articles on [semantic relatedness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_relatedness) and [semantic similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_similarity) may be helpful. And this SO question about [Latent Semantic Analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014927/lsa-latent-semantic-analysis-how-to-code-it-in-php).

You could also look into [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) for words that "sound alike" phonetically.

Comment: Thanks.  Latent semantic analysis looks promising, I will have to read up and see about implementing it.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used it, but you might want to look into [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Answer (score 1):

Jeff talked about something like this on the pod cast to find the Related questions listed on the right side here. ([in podcast 32](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/podcast-32/))

One big tip was to remove all [common words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_common_words_in_English), like "the" "and" "this" etc. This will leave you with more meaningful words to compare.

And here is a similar question [Is there an algorithm that tells the semantic similarity of two phrases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62328/is-there-an-algorithm-that-tells-the-semantic-similarity-of-two-phrases)

Answer (score 0):

This [book](http://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/Keith/Preface.html) may be relevant.

Edit: here is a related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254627/what-tried-and-true-algorithms-for-suggesting-related-articles-are-out-there)

Comment: Thank you.  Information Retrieval is the general topic, and this book probably has good information in it.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite doable for reasonable large texts, however harder for smaller texts.

I did it once like this, and it worked pretty well:

- Filter all "general" words (like a, an, the, in, etc...) (filters about 10-30% of the words)
- Count the frequencies of the remaining words, store the top x of most frequent words, these are your topics.
- As an extra step you can create groups of 2/3/4 subsequent words and compare them with the groups in other texts. I used it as a measure for plagerism.

Answer (score 0):

See Manning and Raghavan course notes about [MinHashing](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs276b/handouts/minhash.ppt) and searching for similar items, and a [C#(?) version](http://blogs.msdn.com/spt/default.aspx). I believe the techniques come from Ullman and Motwani's research.

Answer (score 0):

**Phonetic algorithms**

The article, [Beyond SoundEx - Functions for Fuzzy Searching in MS SQL Server](http://anastasiosyal.com/archive/2009/01/11/18.aspx), shows how to install and use the [SimMetrics](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simmetrics/) library into SQL Server. This library lets you find relative similarity between strings and includes numerous algorithms.

I ended up mostly using [Jaro Winkler](http://www.dcs.shef.ac.uk/~sam/stringmetrics.html#jarowinkler) to match on names. Here's more information where I asked about matching names on SO: [Matching records based on Person Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988050/matching-records-based-on-person-name)

A few algorithms based on [Levenshtein Distance](http://www.dcs.shef.ac.uk/~sam/stringmetrics.html) are also available in the SimMetric library and would probably be useful in your application.