# Fuzzy matching SQL Syntax

Tags: sql-server, ssis

How in SQL can we write something which performs matching similar to the SSIS Fuzzy Matching component ?

What options do we have available using SQL Server features and SQL syntax ?

Thanks,

Comment: How is ranking calculated ? and how is it possible to adjust the sensetivity of matching ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fuzzy grouping in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448297/fuzzy-grouping-in-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [full text indexing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) feature of SQL server, together with the associated functions `CONTAINS`, `RANK`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do fuzzy matching in T-SQL would be using `SOUNDEX()` and `DIFFERENCE()`.

For example

```
select 
soundex('SQL') as 'four-character (SOUNDEX) code' -- Returns S240
, soundex('Sequel') as 'four-character (SOUNDEX) code' -- Returns S240
, difference('SQL', 'Sequel') as  '0: weak or no similarity. 4: strong similarity or the same values.' -- Returns 4
```