# Dynamic SSIS Package for Fuzzy Grouping

Tags: ssis

I have created SSIS Package for Fuzzy Grouping.

I just want to execute package using .config file, which should contain the connection property and inputs for `Fuzzy Grouping` as I have to run the package for many times for different table and column name.

[image]

Question : Is there any solution for creating dynamic ssis package for fuzzy grouping?

Comment: Depending on the type of matches you're attempting to do and the volumes of data (source vs reference), you might be able to roll your own and get a dynamic matcher thing working as you desire but that'll take some programming work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this (dynamic fuzzy lookup)  is going to work. Behind the scenes, the [Fuzzy Lookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/fuzzy-lookup-transformation?view=sql-server-2017) is going to be creating tables of [reference data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/administrator/ms345128(v=sql.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) aka Error-Tolerant Index (ETI) and since each one of your source tables would be unique, you wouldn't be able to cycle through them like you're hoping to do.

I usually suggest a Biml approach (generate all possible packages) but I wonder if the ETI step of the SSIS package creation process is something like the OLE DB Destination Table where you can create the target table. It's a feature in the designer but you can't systematically create the target table. i.e. the object model doesn't have `CreateTargetTable` method associated to the OLE DB Destination. It's just some jiggery pokery that the VS designer allows.

### Caveat

I have not tested this but I'm willing to risk my unicorn points